# How to add custom breakpoints in bootstrap4 and how to use responsive breakpoint mixins in scss

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am working on an angular 5 application which needs to be a responsive app.
I am facing problem to make it reponsive in `1366X768` and `1920X1080` resolutions where in font sizes are different.

**Problem 1:** 
I have overidden breakpoints in my style.scss as follow :

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl:1900px //this is custom breakpoint; after compiling bootstrap does generates col-xxl-* classes
);
```

I have added `xxl` as new breakpoint. Now when I add `col-xxl-*` class to any of my element, that element takes full width jusy like what `col-12` does.
Refer image below :
[image]

For container having border red,I have given `col-xxl-3` class; however it still having full width. Why its resonsive grid classes related to `col-*-3` not getting applied.
I think it should generate css like below:

```
.col-xxl-3 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
}
```

But it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong ?

**Problem 2**

From this [bootstrap responsive breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) , we can use mixins for targeting different resolutions. So in component level scss I have used these mixins as below :

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss';

span.work_catalog {
    @include media-breakpoint-up(xl) { //this will target all above 1200 px as per bootstrap documentation; so this works as u see red border in above image
       border:1px solid red;
    }
}
```

but when I used it like below :

```
 span.work_catalog {
        @include media-breakpoint-up(xxl) { 
           border:1px solid red;
        }
    }
```

this still gets applied for resolution more than 1200px;
What I assume that above css should only gets applied for above 1900px as I have added custom grid breakpoint in my style.scss.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a new `xxl` breakpoint like this. Make sure you @import bootstrap *after* setting the custom `grid-breakpoints`...

```
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 567px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1900px
);

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 567px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1900px
);

 @import "bootstrap";
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/jus43PxWAU

Then the appropriate `xxl-*` classes will be generated...

```
@media (min-width: 1900px) {
    .col-xxl-3 {
        flex: 0 0 25%;
        max-width: 25%;
    }
}
```

For the custom mixin classes, define those after you @import bootstrap...

```
@import "bootstrap";

span.work_catalog {
    @include media-breakpoint-up(xxl) { 
       border:1px solid red;
    }
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/jus43PxWAU (notice the demo sets the xxl breakpoint as 1366px) so when the screen is wider than xxl, `.work_catalog` has the expected red border.

Comment: Classes got generated which solves my problem 1 however , my problem 2 still persist.. I wonder does bootstrap has option to do so.

Comment: I really do think bootstrap doesn't generate mixins `@include media-breakpoint-up(xxl)` for custom breakpoint.

Comment: I successfully used this today, including the breakpoint mixin.
One note, to avoid hard-coding the original breakpoint pixel values, you can use the pre-defined values e.g. "xs: map-get($grid-breakpoints, "xs")"