# Import Bootstrap 4 Sass mixins in codepen.io scss editor

Tags: import, sass, bootstrap-4, codepen, scss-mixins

I was playing around with Bootstrap4 on codepen.io where I import production bundle of bootstrap (bootstrap.bundle.min.js) from a **CDN**.
I was wondering how to import `_breakpoints` within my SCSS? Unable to figure out the path.
I need to use Bootstrap Sass mixins.

Production bundles I'm importing:

- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js

Comment: wanted to use this readily available mixin: `@include media-breakpoint-up(md) { ... }`

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729310/how-to-add-custom-breakpoints-in-bootstrap4-and-how-to-use-responsive-breakpoint/50913555#50913555). The SASS files are included on Codeply when you ref Bootstrap: https://codeply.com/p/pw1PsFKHVu

Comment: @Codeply-er weirdly enough, codepen.io shows a *file not found* error when using `@import "bootstrap";` within the SCSS.

Answer (score 0):

I was to import the `scss` files from `github` in `Pen Settings` > `CSS` > `Add External Stylesheets/Pens`.

**In particular, please keep the order:**

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/main/scss/_functions.scss
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/9030f57db7762a48c813881ef22a99e6cebe99ce/scss/_variables.scss
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/3aaaa01ffa71e5a784451753d5bf9b86a1d5323c/scss/mixins/_breakpoints.scss

[image]

**Eg:** https://codepen.io/borracciablu/pen/JjOweaP
**Note:** Example done with Bootstrap 5, but same technique can be used for Bootstrap 4